# Перенос приложения, использующего динамические библиотеки, на другой компьютер

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, sfml

Спасибо, что зашли на вопрос, возможно Вы именно тот человек, который знает ответ, буду благодарен любой помощи и советам.

Проблема у меня возникла такая: я закончил свое приложение и хотел перенести его на другой компьютер, для теста. Как оно и бывает - пошли ошибки. Конкретно эта связана с ошибкой загрузки динамических библиотек(.dll) из файлов приложения. Суть проблемы заключена в том, что на моем компьютере без этих библиотек программа не запускается, а на другом компьютере она выдает ошибку об отсутствии библиотек. Я работаю в VS2019(Visual Studio 2019), а в самой программе использую SFML, все библиотеки подключал вручную, пакетами NuGet давало ошибку в моей другой программе, поэтому подключал библиотеки сам.
Вот список библиотек, что лежат вместе с .exe-шником моей проги:

- sfml-audio-2.dll
- sfml-audio-d.dll
- sfml-graphics-2.dll
- sfml-graphics-d-2.dll
- sfml-network-2.dll
- sfml-network-d-2.dll
- sfml-system-2.dll
- sfml-system-d-2.dll
- sfml-window-2.dll
- sfml-window-d-2.dll

- *Эти идут по умолчанию от SFML*

- msvcp100d.dll
- msvcp110.dll
- msvcp110d.dll
- msvcr100d.dll
- msvcr110.dll
- msvcr110d.dll

- *Эти относятся к Visual C++ и без них не работает*

- openal32.dll *[Звуковая библиотека, вроде она шла с SFML, но так как я уже не помню, поставил ее отдельно]*

https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads - официальная ссылка на инструмент. Её советуют скачать и поставить, дескать это разом решит все проблемы, так вот нет, не решит, возможно кому-нибудь да поможет, но лично у меня ничего не изменилось.
Второй вариант - поставить Visual C++ именно на компьютере, куда нужно программу и перенести, если уже стоит, то переустановить, но что то я не уверен, что это поможет, поэтому, если Вы так и не посоветуете, не буду этого делать. Если же это решение, то подскажите, как можно сделать установщик, чтобы не приходилось ставить Visual C++ отдельно?

Если это не правильный/не единственный вариант решения данной проблемы, прошу подсказать, как ее можно решить. Спасибо

Comment: Не ответ, но .dll с суффиксом `d` в названии не должны быть нужны, они для дебажных билдов.

Comment: Используйте "Dependencies x64", "Dependency Walker" и т.п. для поиска недостающих dll

Comment: А статически sfml не линкуется?..

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, хорошо, учту, спасибо.

Comment: @dIm0n, понял, спасибо, попробую.

Comment: @Harry, к сожалению, я точно не знаю, но вроде как, нет.

Comment: @SSS_Krut у sfml есть уже собранные статические библиотеки на винде, на других системах можно самому собрать

Comment: @Harry линкуется без проблем.

Comment: @dIm0n, да, есть. Вот только я плохо представляю, как их использовать. Может есть где-то описание, как их использовать?

Comment: @SSS_Krut конечно, есть https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php

Comment: @dIm0n, понял. Большое спасибо :)